# Controling ther max no of threads running simultaneously at a given time in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, worker

I have an array which contains a list of file `@arr=(a.txt,b.txt,c.txt);`

I am iterating the array and processing the files with foreach loop; each line of the file will generate a sql and will run on the DB server.

I want to create one thread with each line of the file and query the DB. I also want to control the max no of threads at a time running simultaneously.

Comment: Can anybody identify where i am making mistake in the bellow code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Thread::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/Thread-Pool-0.33/lib/Thread/Pool.pm) based system. Or any [Boss/Worker](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Boss%2fWorker) model based system.

Comment: If anyody can give an example

Answer (score 1):

That's just a simple worker model, an ideal scenario. No problem.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 5;

sub work {
   my ($dbh, $job) = @_;
   ...
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   my @threads;
   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      push @threads, async {
         my $dbh = ...;
         while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) 
            work($dbh, $job);
         }
      };
   }

   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      $q->enqueue($_);
   }

   $q->enqueue(undef) for 1..@threads;
   $_->join() for @threads;
}
```

Pass the file names to the script as arguments, or assign them to `@ARGV` within the script.

```
local @ARGV = qw( a.txt b.txt c.txt );
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I manually control how many threads to run. I use Hash of the thread id
[code snip]
    my %thr; #my hashes for threads

```
$count=1;
$maxthreads=5;

while (shift (@data) {
  $syncthr = threads->create(sub {callfunction here}, {pass variables});
  $tid = $syncthr->tid; #get the thread ID
  $thr{$tid} = $syncthr;
  if ($count >= $maxthreads) {
    threads->yield();
    while (1) { # loop until threads are completed
    $num_run_threads = keys (%thr);
    foreach $one_thread ( keys %thr ) {
       if ($thr{$one_thread}->is_running() ) { # if thread running check for error state
          if ($err = $thr{$one_thread}->error() } {
             [ do stuff here]
          }
          # otherwise move on to next thread check
       } else { # thread is either completed or has error
          if ($err = $thr{$one_thread}->error()) {
            [ check for error again cann't hurt to double check ]
          }
          if ($err = $thr{$one_thread}->join()) {
             print "Thread completed id: [$one_thread]\n";
          }
          delete $thr{$one_thread}; # delete the hash since the thread is no more
          $num_run_threads = $num_run_threads - 1; # reduce the number of running     threads
       }
    } # close foreach loop
    @threads = threads->list(threads::running); # get threads
    if ($num_run_threads < $maxthreads ) {
      $count = $num_run_threads; # reset the counter to number of threads running
      if ( $#data != -1 ) { # check to make sure we still have data
        last; # exit the infinite while loop
      } else {
        if (@threads) {
          next; # we still have threads continue with processing
        } else {
          { no more threads to process exit program or do something else }
        }
      } # end else
    } # end threads running
    } # end the while statement
    #Check the threads to see if they are joinable
    undef @threads;
    @threads = threads->joinable()
    if (@threads) {
      foreach $mthread(@threads) {
        if ($mthreads != 0) {
          $thr->join();
        }
      } #end foreach
    } #end @threads
  } #end the if statement
  $count++; Increment the counter to get to number of max threads to spawn
}
```

This is by no means a complete program. Furthermore, I have changed it to be very bland. However, I've been using this for a while with success. Especially in the OO Perl. This works for me and have quite a lot of uses. I maybe missing a few more error checking especially with timeout but I do that in the thread itself. Which by the way the thread is actually a sub routine that I am calling.